# Rails/Ruby 1.9: Is there a better way to put Unicode in source files than sticking # encoding at the top of every file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, utf-8

I just upgraded to Rails 3 and Ruby 1.9. All of my source files that used Unicode inside of them (such as emdashes) caused problems until I found out that you now need to include the following magic comment on top of each source file:

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

Is there a better way to do this? It'd be nice if it just automatically treated every source file as utf-8 like Rails 2.3/Ruby 1.8 did, and I don't see any apparent disadvantage from doing so.

In my application.rb I already have the following, but I can't tell that it does anything:

```
config.encoding = "utf-8"
```

Comment: Sorry for using this space for a rant, but I find it absolutely amazing that they chose ASCII as the default charset. I mean, I get that if you're Japanese UTF-8 isn't as awesome as it seems to us westerners, but ASCII was just about the worst decision they could have made.

Comment: I'm trying the `encoding` setting in the `.rb` file, but it doesn't work for me (same error Invalid char ...) on Windows. What OS are you on and is the encoding statement working for you ?

Comment: @Zabba I'm on Ubuntu and the encoding statement is working for me. You're pasting it in exactly as I typed it with the comment # right?

Comment: nothing working for me, typed what you wrote exactly. Also see if this post helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484071/unicode-characters-in-a-ruby-script/3484152#3484152

Answer (score 4):

i found only `rake check_encoding_headers` it add the magic comment to all files.

Comment: Nice find. Here's the URL for that rake task: http://snaprails.tumblr.com/post/556378216/porting-an-application-to-ruby-1-9. Remember to backup everything first!!

Answer (score 0):

There is also [a gem](https://github.com/m-ryan/magic_encoding) for adding encodings to all headers.