# why does my vim encoding and ruby encoding not agree?

Tags: ruby, vim, encoding

In the ruby file:

```
p __ENCODING__

#<Encoding:US-ASCII>
```

In vim:

```
set encoding?
encoding=utf-8
```

This is causing me grief (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495486/ruby-syntax-error-with-multiple-language-in-hash), which is patched but I still don't understand why the file shows as ASCII by ruby and utf-8 by vim.

Comment: Do you use "magic comment" as it suggested in the question you are referring to?

Comment: @NIA Yes I am, as I said above (it's patched), but that's not the question. I want to know why they don't agree.

Comment: `set encoding` gives you the internal encoding used by vim itself, not the encoding of the file you're editing.

Comment: @pixelearth, see my edit to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

As @melpomene commented, `:set encoding` tells you what encoding is used internally by Vim.

`:set fileencoding` will tell you what encoding Vim decided to use for your document. The possible values are given by the `fileencodings` option. ASCII is not part of the default list as it's usually handled transparently by the other encodings listed.

But that part of your question is puzzling me:

> but I still don't understand why the file is ASCII

because it looks like you *actively* want that file to be treated as ASCII by the interpreter.

Anyway, that encoding directive is only used by Ruby: it doesn't mean that the file is *actually* encoded as ASCII or that Vim is supposed to care about it and treat it in a special way.

In short, whether your file is actually encoded in ASCII or not, Vim doesn't care.

So… what do you want exactly? That vim sets its `fileencoding` option to ASCII when you open a supposedly ASCII file? That your supposedly ASCII file be converted to another encoding?

***edit***

1. With that directive, you explicitely tell Ruby that the file's content must be treated as ASCII and Ruby says "OK, that's ASCII, if you say so.".
2. This directive doesn't change *anything* to the actual encoding of the file. It could be utf-8, latin1 or whatever.
3. Vim doesn't understand that directive.
4. Vim chooses the encoding it uses for that file according to a number of rules you should read about in `:h encoding`, `:h fileencoding` and `:h fileencodings`.
5. Vim doesn't treat ASCII in a special "ASCII" way, it just handles it has the subset of utf-8 that it is.

So, before we go further, please verify:

- the encoding of the file with something like `$ file /path/to/file`
- the `fileencoding` Vim uses for that file with `:set fileencoding`